# How to sort a list of 2D points using C#?

Tags: c#

Sort a list of points in descending order according to X and then Y.

Comment: If you're looking for some help, what have you previously tried? What code have you written that doesn't work?

Comment: This is not a place where people do homework for you

Comment: How is the order of points defined? First x then y, distance from origin, ...?

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan - maybe it's not a place to solve homeworks for newbies - anyway - the rest of community can learn a lot. I personally do not feel the need to take responsibility for the morality of developers around the world - maybe it's bad for me - but what counts is the sum of the profits for all the community.

Answer (score 10):

```
list.Sort((a,b)=>{
    int result = a.X.CompareTo(b.X);
    if(result==0) result = a.Y.CompareTo(b.Y);
    return result;
});
```

Answer (score 6):

An alternative way to Marc Gravell´s answer (which will sort the list itself) where you get an `IEnumerable<T>` which can be made a list with `.ToList()` is the LINQ syntax:

```
var ordered = from v in yourList
              orderby v.X, v.Y
              select v;

var orderedList = ordered.ToList();
```

But unless you don't want to actually sort the list itself or you only have, let's say an `IEnumerable`, `List.Sort` would be better.

Comment: LINQ looks quite 'stylish' for mentioned case and because it's simple case - probably it will be quite efficient too.

Comment: I believe `List.Sort` will be a bit more efficient but I don't know for sure and it properly doesn't matter anyway :) It should be noted, however, that the two solutions is not semantically equivalent (even with `yourList = *query with yourList*.ToList()`) because others could have a reference to the old list.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Point> sortedList = MyList.Sort(
    delegate(Point p1, Point p2) 
    {
        int r = p1.x.CompareTo(p2.x); 
        if(r.Equals(0)) return p1.y.CompareTo(p2.y);
        else return r;
    }
);
```

Comment: Only sorts by x and not first by x then by y

Answer (score 0):

If the commenters are indeed correct, and you're searching for a solution to a homework problem, I suspect the real assignment is teaching you how to sort integer values. So I'll just help get you started.

**Hint:** The [`Point` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.aspx) has two properties that you may find useful, `X` and `Y`, which return the coordinate values for those two axes, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods to sort a list.

For example, to sort your list from smallest (x, y) to biggest you can try this algorithm:

1. Compare the first item in the list with the second
2. If the second point is smaller than the first `(x1 > x2 || (x1 == x2 && y1 > y2))` then swap them around
3. Compare the second point with the third in the same way, and so on until you get to the end of the list
4. Go back to the beginning of the list and run the comparisons again until the last but one element
5. Repeat step 4 but stopping one element earlier each time until you've got no elements left to sort

This is an inefficient algorithm, but it will get the job done.

For better algorithms, have a look at http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/